# Return first date and previous dates

Tags: sql, sqldatetime

There is a custid with 3 dates .

I want to return first date and then its previous date .

data should look like:

```
custid first       previous
11     2019-06-10  2019-06-15
11     2019-06-10  2019-07-10
```

I have done it but I'm not able to put it in 2nd row.

```
SELECT A.PersonID ,min(a.date) as first,b.date as previous,c.date as previous from Persons as a
INNER JOIN (select PersonID ,date from Persons) b
on a.PersonID
=b.PersonID  AND 
a.date<
b.date
INNER JOIN (select PersonID ,date from Persons) c
            on b.PersonID=
c.PersonID
           AND b.date<
c.date
```

Output which I'm getting:

```
personid first         previous          previous
11       2019-06-10    2019-06-15            2019-07-10
```

I want it to look like:

```
custid first       previous
11     2019-06-10  2019-06-15
11     2019-06-10  2019-07-10
```

Comment: What database are you using ? Please be specific

Comment: The description of the [tag:sql] tag says *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used**.* Please edit to add that DBMS tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the 3rd inner join table. Since your using min() with other columns, this should be accompanied by Group By.

```
select
  a.PersonID as custid,
  min(a.date) as first,
  b.date as previous     
from
  Persons as a
inner join Persons b on a.PersonID = b.PersonID and b.date > a.date
group by a.PersonID, b.date
```